# Basic question of General relativity about covariant derivative

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation

I was reading the book of  Wald on General relativity. And  in the page number (33) he derives the equation for the action  of $\nabla_{a}$ over a tensor of rank $(k,l)$.

This is the equation (3.1.14):
$$\nabla_{a} T^{b_{1}...b_{k}} {}_{c_{1}...c_{l}}= \tilde{\nabla}_{a} T^{b_{1}...b_{k}}{}_{c_{1}...c_{l}} 
+\sum_{i}C^{b_i}_{ad}T^{b_{1}...d...b_{k}}{}_{c_{1}...c_{k}}  -\sum_{j}C^{d}_{ac_{j}}T^{b_{1}...b_{l}}{}_{c_{1}...d...c_{l}}.  
$$

In the next page he says that the most import application of the equation (3.1.14) araises in the case where $\tilde{\nabla}_{a}$ is equal to is equal to the usual operator $\partial_{a}$ in that case $C^{c}_{ab}$ is equal to the Christoffel symbol.

My question is what happen if I choose $\nabla_{a}=\partial_{a}$. In that case $C^{c}_{ab}$ is also equal to Christoffel symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\nabla_a$ is a covariant derivative. In the context instead of $\partial_a$ is used $\tilde\nabla_a$. $C$ coefficients are the connections, and another name for them is Christoffel symbols. If you take partial derivative $\partial_a$  of the $(k,l)$ tensor, instead of the covariant derivative, as you say $\nabla_a=\partial_a$, it will not be the covariant and the connection terms/Christoffel symbols in the identity disappear.

Or more precisely, choosing $\nabla_a=\partial_a$ means replacing the covariant derivative of the tensor with the ordinary partial derivative. In the ordinary derivative, there is no notion of the Christoffel symbols. In your context, they are zero, ${C^c_{ab}}=0$.
After replacing $\nabla_a$ with $\partial_a$
$$\nabla_{a} T^{b_{1}...b_{k}} {}_{c_{1}...c_{l}}=\partial_{a} T^{b_{1}...b_{k}} {}_{c_{1}...c_{l}}=
 \tilde{\nabla}_{a} T^{b_{1}...b_{k}}{}_{c_{1}...c_{l}} 
.  
$$

Answer (score 1):

The Christoffel symbols are a certain set of symbols that are defined by certain derivatives of the metric invariant of your choice of connection. The $C$ symbols which I assume here is the connection will equal the Christoffel symbols if you require the covariant derivative to be metric compatible ($\nabla_a g_{bc} = 0$) and symmetric ($C^c_{ab}=C^c_{ba}$).

The reason this choice is so relevant is because metric compatible means the angle between two vectors don't change when transported and symmetric means the transport is path independent. Both are of course natural properties we would want.